# rbind a list and recover names

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I was searching the interwebs for a way to create a data frame from a list but retain the names of the list elements as a column by itself. I saw [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/22) from back in 2014 but a lot of the functions are deprecated and/or none of them are doing what I'm trying to do.

Here's what I've done so far but it's a hacky way of doing it.

```
RNGkind("Mersenne-Twister")
set.seed(42)

my_list <- list(a = rnorm(22, 4, 1),
                b = sample(1:1000, 10, replace = T),
                c = rep(1334, 5))

my_df <- data.frame(names = rep(names(my_list), do.call(c, lapply(my_list, length))),
      values = do.call(c, my_list))
```

Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this? I'm not much of a `tidyverse` or `tidyr` but I'm up for anything if it's more streamlined than this.

Comment: Could you make `my_list$c` a bit smaller? 5 cases should be enough to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `stack` from `base R`

```
my_df2 <- stack(my_list)[2:1]
all.equal(my_df, my_df2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(my_list) %>%
   unnest(value)
```